# why is there an index range scan on max() query?

Tags: oracle, index, execution-plan, max

I have a table that logs the transmission of data to another system.

```
create table transfer_log (id number(10),
                           fk_data number(10),
                           first_sent_time date,
                           last_sent_time date,
                           transfer_status number(3),
                           error_message varchar2(250));

create unique index pk_transfer_log on transfer_log (id);
alter table transfer_log add constraint pk_transfer_log primary key (id);

create index idx_transfer_log_status on transfer_log (transfer_status, last_sent_time desc);
```

The transfer_status column stores the HTTP status from sending the data.
transfer_status is never null (initially 0), last_sent_time is initially null.
So I have a health check, to see when the last successful transmission was:

```
select
  max(d.last_sent_time)
from
  transfer_log d
where
  d.transfer_status = 200
;
```

and I hoped the index would make this query fast. But it's close to 1sec now and the execution plan doesn't look good:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id | Operation           | Name                    | Rows    | Bytes   | Cost | Time |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  0 | SELECT STATEMENT    |                         |       1 |       6 | 2624 |      |
|  1 |   SORT AGGREGATE    |                         |       1 |       6 |      |      |
|  2 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN | IDX_TRANSFER_LOG_STATUS | 1272670 | 7636020 | 2624 |      |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I hoped the index (especially with the descending last_sent_time) would make this query fast as only the first entry needs to be read.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop that index and create without desc:

```
create index idx_transfer_log_status on transfer_log (transfer_status, last_sent_time);
```

The database can decide to read an ascending index in descending order. The last entry can be read as quickly as the first entry.

But even better, it can recognize a case when you search for a MIN/MAX value and use the operation for that:

```
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL_ID  6q8sbnqkajz74, child number 1
-------------------------------------
select   max(d.last_sent_time) from   transfer_log d where
d.transfer_status = 200

Plan hash value: 3076158531

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name                    | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |                         |       |       |     2 (100)|          |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE              |                         |     1 |    11 |            |          |
|   2 |   FIRST ROW                  |                         |     1 |    11 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN (MIN/MAX)| IDX_TRANSFER_LOG_STATUS |     1 |    11 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

  3 - access("D"."TRANSFER_STATUS"=200)
```

Unfortunately this does not work with a `desc` index.

Comment: that was unexpected! And I thought I was extra smart by making it desc. The query is fast now (30ms), but the cost still shows as 2207.

Comment: So what's the point in having a `DESC` index at all if the `database can decide to read an ascending index in descending order`? **Plus**, the `DESC` index isn't able to deal with MIN()/MAX() (or at least not efficiently)? Puzzled...